# What's the most efficient way to make bitwise operations in a C array

Tags: c, performance, micro-optimization

I have a C array like:

```
char byte_array[10];
```

And another one that acts as a mask:

```
char byte_mask[10];
```

I would like to do get another array that is the result from the first one plus the second one using a bitwise operation, on each byte.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
for ( i = 10 ; i-- > 0 ; )
    result_array[i] = byte_array[i] & byte_mask[i];
```

- Going backwards pre-loads processor cache-lines.
- Including the decrement in the compare can save some instructions.

This will work for all arrays and processors.  However, if you know your arrays are word-aligned, a faster method is to cast to a larger type and do the same calculation.

For example, let's say `n=16` instead of `n=10`.  Then this would be much faster:

```
uint32_t* input32 = (uint32_t*)byte_array;
uint32_t* mask32 = (uint32_t*)byte_mask;
uint32_t* result32 = (uint32_t*)result_array;
for ( i = 4 ; i-- > 0 ; )
    result32[i] = input32[i] & mask32[i];
```

(Of course you need a proper type for `uint32_t`, and if `n` is not a power of 2 you need to clean up the beginning and/or ending so that the 32-bit stuff is aligned.)

Variation: The question specifically calls for the results to be placed in a separate array, however it would almost certainly be faster to modify the input array in-place.

Comment: Wait, does the cache prefetcher work better in reverse? I thought it only prefetched going forwards.

Comment: Worrying about pre-loading processor cache-lines seems like a severe premature optimization.

Comment: @Trent -- the *point* of the question is optimization.  Also going backwards is no slower, so you might as well.

@Crashworks -- remember that cache lines are aligned, typically on massive boundaries, so typically it has to pull in bytes prior to the ones you're asking for.

Comment: Any statements regarding cache is going to be processor specific.  I don't see where the OP states what HW this code will execute on.

Comment: I appreciate this explanation. I will use this method. I don't fully understand the cache, so I can't really tell what's going on at that level.

Comment: Another advantage of going backwards is that it's easier for the CPU to compare the counter to a constant 0 than to compare it with a variable.  It avoids a memory access, or frees up a register, depending on if the count is stored in a register.

Comment: Why a power of 2? Wouldn't a multiple of a word size work? You assume 32 bit word here?

Comment: Nice answer Jason. 

I would add one other option for the aligned case: use vector operations if the processor supports them. Such as SSE on x86. GCC and Intel C++ both support intrinsics that make it easy to "vectorize" loops like the one above. Google "gcc sse instrinsics" for some good links.

Comment: @Ian - Yes any multiple of word size works, ALSO ASSUMING that the char arrays in question are themselves word-aligned.  Also you are right that I'm assuming 32-bit processor; it must be tuned to the processor in question.  Although, assuming 32-bit is still faster than byte-wise on almost any proc.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make it faster, make sure that byte_array has length that is multiple of 4 (8 on 64-bit machines), and then:

```
char byte_array[12];
char byte_mask[12];
/* Checks for proper alignment */
assert(((unsigned int)(void *)byte_array) & 3 == 0);
assert(((unsigned int)(void *)byte_mask) & 3 == 0);
for (i = 0; i < (10+3)/4; i++) {
  ((unsigned int *)(byte_array))[i] &= ((unsigned int *)(byte_mask))[i];
}
```

This is much faster than doing it byte per byte.

(Note that this is in-place mutation; if you want to keep the original byte_array also, then you obviously need to store the results in another array instead.)

Comment: 10/4 == 2, so this only processes 8 chars. In addition, on some non-x86 architectures this may raise a bus error due to unaligned memory accesses.

Comment: bk1e: you are right, i < 10/4 is wrong. The comment about bus error is also correct. I will edit the answer.

Comment: If it is not a multiple of 4/8, use duff's device :)

Answer (score 1):

```
\#define CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE    (10)
\#define INT_ARRAY_SIZE     ((CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE/ (sizeof (unsigned int)) + 1)

typedef union _arr_tag_ {

    char          byte_array [CHAR_ARRAY_SIZE];
    unsigned int  int_array [INT_ARRAY_SIZE]; 

} arr_tag;
```

Now int_array for masking. This might work for both 32bit and 64 bit processors.

```
arr_tag arr_src, arr_result, arr_mask;

for (int i = 0; i < INT_ARRAY_SIZE; i ++) {
    arr_result.int_array [i] = arr_src.int_array[i] & arr_mask.int_array [i];
}
```

Try this, code might also look clean.