# What is the most efficient way to merge byte arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Say I have two arrays of char, and each position is either 1 or 0.
The two arrays are calculated in different processes and then sent back to a master to be combined, so each one only writes to a certain range of their array:

p1 : [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

p2 : [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

goal: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]

However, these could be very large arrays. Is there a super fast way of doing this besides just looping over one of them?

To clarify, they should be OR'd.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668280/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-make-bitwise-operations-in-a-c-array

Comment: Do you have to send the 0's and 1's as char's? Could you pack the bits to integers before sending them to the master? Then you could just xor the two integers in the master.

Comment: @Makis, this is a neat micro-optimization, but if they're contiguous ranges it won't help at all with large ranges - you'll just be doing a lot of wasted `x ^ 0` and `0 ^ x` operations. It would be a good idea if the bits each process is charged with were interleaved.

Comment: yes i suppose i could use something like a bit array or integers...i just used char as it is one byte and the implementation was very simple.

Comment: Your question is not very clear - when you say "merge", are you just OR-ing these arrays together ?

Comment: yeh just or-ing them together

Comment: @bdonlan: True, if you have lots of 0's. The question didn't specify this, though. It would be interesting to see if it really is faster to do this any other way, though, without any knowledge of the incoming values (i.e. if you would know that the next n values are 0's), since xor is 1 cycle operation. So you need two memory fetches + xor + memory write per 32 bits (on a 32-bit processor).

Comment: @Makis, no, if you have each process handling a different contiguous range, there's no point in xoring the ranges they don't overlap on, is what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming byte granularity is good enough, you'd probably want to use `memcpy` to copy them into the output array:

```
memcpy(goal, p2, 4);
memcpy(goal + 4, p1 + 4, 4);
```

You can further optimize this by letting `p1` and `p2` only contain their own ranges, eg:

```
char p1[4] = { 1, 1, 0, 1 };
char p2[4] = { 1, 0, 1, 1 };
char goal[8];
memcpy(goal, p2, 4);
memcpy(goal + 4, p1, 4);
```

Note that you may also want to look into bit vector packing - where you pack eight bits into each char. This will save a lot of memory for large arrays, although it complicates access.

Comment: I might be able to do it like this, but the next step for me was going to be having the worker processors combine with each other before sending it to the master. would there be any overhead to reallocating several small times as opposed to one large allocation?

Comment: Yes, there will be overhead. You'd be better off using shared memory and having them all write into the final goal array.

Comment: not if the processors are distributed over several machines :P

Comment: Then it's best to just pass results straight to the master, I'd think. The master's going to receive the same amount of data in any case, after all. Just make sure you only send the ranges each slave is responsible for (not an entire array where most of it is blank)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

1. Profiling to make sure this is really a bottleneck.
2. Investigate doing this "vector-style", i.e. by aligning the byte arrays and then processing, using regular linear loops, as many bytes as possible using single machine operations, perhaps by accessing as `unsigned long long`.
3. Rearranging so that the child processes report in a more efficient format, perhaps using some kind of run-length compression.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on different processors Perhaps you should consider using MPI library with a reduction operation, it is extremely fast

```
MPI_Reduce(p, goal, size, MPI_CHAR, MPI_LOR, goal_process_id, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

If you are using different threads, then OpenMP is also good in terms of code simplicity (this is quick and dirty code):

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(|, out)
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
  out[i] = p1[i] * p2[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason *why* arrays are used? Because the most efficient way, both in terms of speed and memory consumption, is no doubt to actually work on byte level. Instead of tossing arrays back and forth needlessly.

Perhaps something like this?

```
uint8 proc_n (void)
{
  uint8 result = 0x00;
  uint8 i;

  for(i=0; i<8; i++)
  {
    if(something)
    {
      result |= (0x01 << i);
    }
  }

  return result;
}



typedef uint8 (*Proc_ptr)(void);

Proc_ptr proc_array [PROCESSES] =
{
  proc_1,
  proc_2,
  ...
};

uint8 result = 0x00;

for(i=0; i<PROCESSES; i++)
{
  result |= proc_array[i]();
}
```